# Is the "op" lattice $\mathscr{L}^\perp_{\mathscr H}$ of subspaces of a Hilbert space $\mathscr H$ also atomistic with the covering property?

Tags: hilbert-space

Let $\mathscr{L}_{\mathscr H}$ denote the usual lattice of subspaces of a Hilbert space $\mathscr H$, where for $p,q\in\mathscr H$ we write $p\leq q$ iff $p$ is a subspace of $q$. Then, as discussed in, e.g., Beltrametti&Cassinelli https://books.google.com/books?id=yWoq_MRKAgcC&pg=PA98, this lattice is atomistic with the covering property. (And another discussion of atomistic lattices with the covering property is in Section 4.2.5 (pages 4-10 and 4-11) of https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.5627)

(That is, very briefly, $0$ is the weakest element, i.e., $\forall p\in{\mathscr L_H}:0\leq p$, and pure states $a\in{\mathscr L_H}$ (one-dimensional subspaces) are "atoms", i.e., $\forall p\in{\mathscr L_H}:0\leq p\leq a\implies 0=p\mbox{ .or. }p=a$. And then the covering property means $\forall p\in{\mathscr L_H}: a\not\leq p\implies \not\exists q|p\leq q\leq p\sqcup a$.)

Now consider the "op" lattice  $\mathscr{L}^\perp_{\mathscr H}$, where $q\leq p$ in $\mathscr{L}_{\mathscr H}$ means $p\leq q$ in $\mathscr{L}^\perp_{\mathscr H}$. Then, e.g., $0^\perp={\mathscr H}$ is now the weakest element in $\mathscr{L}^\perp_{\mathscr H}$. So can we now say that...
    (a) the orthocomplements of pure states are the atoms of $\mathscr{L}^\perp_{\mathscr H}$, and
    (b) they also possess the corresponding covering property with respect to this lattice?
And can you prove it, or even better (and presumably easier) cite a proof? Note that by "prove", I mean assume it's already been proven for $\mathscr{L}_{\mathscr H}$ (which it has), and then you only need prove it must also be true for $\mathscr{L}^\perp_{\mathscr H}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on whether $\mathcal L_{\mathcal H}$ is the lattice of all subspaces of $\mathcal H$, or just *closed* subspaces.

In the first cas, the result is not true : the orthocomplements of pure states are *closed* hyperplanes of $\mathcal H$, while atoms of $\mathcal L_{\mathcal H}^\perp$ are maximal proper subspaces, ie hyperplanes, but not necessarily closed.

If we consider only closed subspace, the result is true.

For $p,q\in\mathcal L_\mathcal H$, you have :
$$p\leq q^\perp \Longleftrightarrow p^\perp \geq q$$
This means that we have a [monotone Galois connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection#(Monotone)_Galois_connection) $\mathcal L_{\mathcal H}\leftrightarrows \mathcal L_{\mathcal H}^\perp$, whose closure operator is the toplogical closure. Since this is the identity on closed subspaces, we have an isomorphism of lattices $\mathcal L_{\mathcal H} \simeq \mathcal L_{\mathcal H}^\perp$ which maps pure states (which are the atoms of $\mathcal L_{\mathcal H}$) to closed hyperplanes (which therefore are the atoms of $\mathcal L_{\mathcal H}^\perp$). The covering property is also preserved.

Comment: Thanks, SF. So I take it that "isomorphism of lattices" is the linchpin of the proof. Wouldn't that simply be true for any orthocomplemented lattice??? And if that's the case, then my whole question seems a lot more trivial than I'd originally imagined. By the way, I take it that the atomistic property is also preserved, i.e., $\forall p\in{\mathscr L_H}:p=\sqcup\{atom\in{\mathscr L_H}|atom\leq p\}$. Thanks, again.

Comment: Oops... I (obviously) meant $\forall p\in{\mathscr L^\perp_H}:p=\sqcup\{atom\in{\mathscr L^\perp_H}|atom\leq p\}$ above. But apparently, "comments can only be edited for five minutes", preventing me from fixing the original.